# MySQL update datetime records from GMT+7 to UTC

Tags: mysql, datetime, timezone

In my database table there is a `created_at` column which has records in `Y-m-d H:i:s` GMT+7 format, i want to update all the `created_at` records into UTC format, for example:

```
/*Old Records in GMT+7 format*/
+-------------------+
|    created_at     |
+-------------------+
|2018-09-30 12:11:25|
|2018-10-01 02:44:05|
|2018-10-02 14:45:15|
+-------------------+


/*New Records in UTC format*/
+-------------------+
|    created_at     |
+-------------------+
|2018-09-30 05:11:25|
|2018-09-30 19:44:05|
|2018-10-02 07:45:15|
+-------------------+
```

Comment: Is it guaranteed to be +7 for _all_ dates or something like +7 / +8 depending on time of year?

Comment: @SalmanA yes because i've saved it that way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use CONVERT_TZ(created_at,'+00:00','-7:00'):

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4b864e6ba95cba66b5fa8da271d443de)

```
SELECT created_at,CONVERT_TZ(created_at,'+00:00','-7:00');
```

Output:

```
createddate          utctime
2018-10-02 08:56:29  2018-10-02 01:56:29
```

Comment: Why didn't you specify `CONVERT_TZ(created_at,'+07:00','00:00')`?

Comment: it's already it +7 format which need to convert in UTC that's why '+00:00','-7:00' but yes it's static, It should not change with daylight saving

Comment: Although the result is correct, the function signature is `date, from_tz, to_tz`, so `+07:00` should come first.